# Open swf file than works with socket

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain, flash-cs5, flash

Sorry for my bad English.

I have the following problem:

I have a .fla file, that works with Socket class. There is a server(written in Delphi XE, but it does not matter). I connect to it from my .fla.
When i execute my .fla from within Flash Professional CS5 everything works fine. But when i tried to execute resulting .swf from Explorer(Win 7, Flash Player 10) i got an error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2010: Local-with-filesystem SWF files are not
 permitted to use sockets. at flash.net::Socket/internalConnect() at
 flash.net::Socket/connect() at payterminal::TLogger() at
 payterminal::TMainTerminalClass() at
 testterminal_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Socket connects to the server as follows:

*Sock.connect('127.0.0.1', 5243);*

I tried to change setting "Local playback security" in "File->Publish settings" to "Access network only.

Ok. Flash player starts without errors, but it's send to server the following message:

```
<policy-file-request/>
```

After this socket connection closes.

I also tried to use the method Security.AllowDomain(), but it did not made no positive results.

There was another method i tried. The server has two listening sockets. The first listening on port 843. When this socket receive the message policy-file-request it send to .swf the crossdomain file, like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>  <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
 "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">  <!-- Policy
 file for xmlsocket://socks.mysite.com -->  <cross-domain-policy>  
     <allow-access-from domain="*"/>  
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

After it the socket(843) closes.
But the second listening socket gets the same message: .

After all this, my .swf is still open in Flash Player with no errors, but the socket connection is not happening.
I tried different crossdomain-files, but all my attempts led me to same result.

That's the problem i have. I look forward to your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user976479 this is perfectly normal behavior.
Flash player will first try to obtain the master xml policy file on port 843 and then try 5243 if it doesn't find a master.
Once the server responds to the request for the crossdomain flash player will close the connection(always).
I use the following crossdomain.xml for my socket server.
Remember once the domain policy is recieved you have to have the flash player reconnect a second time. The second time you will not be disconnected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFileSocket.xsd">
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"  />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

One last thing.
use a port higher then 10k as the lower ports are usually reserved for other applications and there maybe be a conflict with that.

Comment: As a side note let me add that when the server sends the request "<policy-file-request/>" it is asking for the crossdomain at that time you need to respond with the crossdomain policy as I stated with the xml I posted. After that the client socket will disconnect and the client will have to reconnect to the server. Only at that time can you send requests through the socket. I suggest reading up on what a master policy file is. I personally keep crossdomain.xml on each port I use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your cross-domain file.

Flash player's security features do not allow a local (file:// protocol) file to access the internet. To test your swf in a browser, you'll have to upload it to your server and then test it.

Or, you could download a server to install on your local machine for testing.
I use [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

EDIT: Since you are already running a local server, try uploading to that. Then access your swf as http://127.0.0.1/mySwf.swf

Comment: Flash player's security features do not allow a local (file:\\ domain) file to access the internet.???????? really? Come on read what you type before you post it.

Comment: By default, Flash will put all local running SWFs inside the local-with-filesystem Sandbox, which will prevent that SWF from making any network calls.  You can, however, choose a different sandbox at compile-time.  Security guide: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

Comment: @The_asMan you could have corrected the file:\\ domain to file:// protocol, instead of posting an completely unnecessary comment..

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi my comment was because it is completely untrue what I quoted before. I access networked data from my local file system all the time. Plus the op clearly stated there was a connection being made it was just dropped.

Comment: @The_asMan Well, yeah. The default settings prevent any network access. And it isn't advisable to change these settings because other (malicious) flash movies can then misuse your settings. So for all practical purposes, I would say FP blocks requests from the local file:// protocol