# Flex: Error #2048 when connecting to a WebSocket

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, websocket

I've implemented a simple Flex application that tries to connect to a server via the WebSocket protocol. Running the app in the Flash Builder 4.6 debugger everything works fine. So I installed the application on my server and now I get Error #2048 after a while. #2048 seems to be an error concerning security.

The server provides this crossdomain.xml:

**Updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFileSocket.xsd">
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"  />
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Edit:** It's provided by calling

```
Security.loadPolicyFile('http://myserver:8081/crossdomain.xml');
```

I can see in the web server logs that the client loads it.

I'm using [AS3WebSocket](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket) as the WebSocket implementation for Flex.

This is how I set up the WebSocket object:

```
websocket = new WebSocket(url, "*", 'dummy', 5000);
// adding several event handler ...
websocket.connect();
```

The browser connects to the server with

```
http://myserver:8081
```

The *url* parameter holds

```
ws://myserver:8081/data
```

Why does it work locally with the Flash Builder and not on my server? What am I missing?

Comment: What port is crossdomain being dished out on.

Comment: The very first line executed in the Flex app is _Security.loadPolicyFile('httpaddressofmyserver:8081/crossdomain.xml');_. And it's loaded from the app. That much I can see in the logs of my web server.

Comment: please refer to my other post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634266/open-swf-file-than-works-with-socket/7637329#7637329

Comment: Hi, I think I tried everything you advised in your post. I've tried your crossdomain.xml. Same error. Why does this happen when I deliver the app from a server? It works locally even though I connect to the same server via WebSocket.

Comment: http:////myserver:8081/crossdomain.xml is not in the same domain as ws://myserver:8081/data for that matter where is the .com

Comment: myserver is just a placeholder. I use an IP address. Where is the difference. AFAIK the protocol is not part of the domain.

Comment: 2 more things I can think of do you have allownetworking = "all" set in your embed code? and there is a specific way to load the policy file on sockets Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://"+host+":"+port); http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29 test with trace(Security.sandboxType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. I somehow missed the information that I needed a special [policy server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) running for socket policies on port 843 providing the policy file via TCP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"  />
```

leave out the "permitted-cross-domain-policies="none" bit.

Try that for now.
make it more secure when everything works.

Comment: I've changed the crossdomain.xml but I still get error #2048. It loads the file. That's for sure. Is there any way to find out exactly what causes the security error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check Firewall Security [internal and external access to port] this can be one of the cause to your problem.

Please check below link:-
http://flexhappycoding.blogspot.in

Comment: Thanks for the tipp but the port is open. I can connect to the port via HTTP from a browser. Just the Socket connection can't connect and it seems it does not try because of security issues specific to Flex/Flash.